# Can't log into other computers from my Macbook

Tags: macos, mac, macbook, mac-mini

This has been very frustrating for me and I can't seem to find any info through a google search.  My setup - Mac Mini as a media center, MacBook Air and older Macbook (2005 I believe).  I cannot sign into the Mac Mini or the MacBook Air from the MacBook.  When I try to sign into the Air, it either times out or tells me that my username and password are incorrect (not possible).  When I try to sign into the Mac Mini it doesn't even give me the option.  The Mini shows up in the shared area of the finder but when I highlight it, nothing happens.  I can sign into the MacBook from both of the other computers, though.

Comment: The Mountain Lion does not like Leopard (afs/appletalk) try snow leopard on the old MacBook

Comment: @datasmid Do you have a reference for that claim?

Comment: I'm sorry I should have included that information in my original post. The Mini and the old Macbook are both running Snow Leopard and the Air is running Lion.

Comment: Do reference, only my own frustration with it